# iPad iOS 8.1.3 load iPhone splash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

In my iOS app, I have added all image but iPad splash screen is not showing. But it shows iOS before 8.00 not in iOS 8.00. Each time it is loading the iPhone splash.
Any solution?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 8.x.x you can use LaunchScreen.xib

sets LaunchScreen.xib for iOS 8 launch screen file

[image: sets LaunchScreen.xib for iOS 8 launch screen file]

Or, to use images.xcassets, leave Launch Screen File in blank. Check if file  LaunchScreen.xib exist and delete from xcode.

Comment: CCastro, i did it all. Not working. just feeling horrible. :(

Comment: you are right but i had also clean  project , delete the cache also. It's a rubbish behaviour of xcode. thanks anyway. accepted your answer friend. :) CCastro